# Angular mat-icon doesn't render svgs with masks

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular-material, material-design

I have a series of `.svgs` exported from Sketch (see sample below) that I've registered to the `MatIconRegistry`, and am displaying using the `mat-icon` component.

However I've noticed that any icons that use masks in Sketch (exported as `<defs>`) don't show properly, and sometimes show the wrong icon altogether.

I know this is an issue with `mat-icon` since the files render fine in the browser. Also `mat-icon` renders fine when the source file does not use masks (However we can't guarantee that the `svgs` won't have a mask)

Does anyone know of a way to fix this, either in Sketch or in Angular?

#### `icon-registry.service.ts`

```js
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyIconRegistry {
  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, 
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        'dot',
        'path/to/icon-dot.svg'
      )
  }
}
```

#### `myComponent.component.ts`

```js
...
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<mat-icon svgIcon="dot"></mat-icon>`,
  styleUrls: ['./icon.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
})
...
```

#### myModule.module.ts

```js
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  providers: [MyIconRegistry],
  imports: [CommonModule, MatIconModule, HttpClientModule],
  exports: [MyComponent],
})
```

#### `icon-dot.svg`

```html
<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com -->
    <title>icon-dot</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <circle id="path-1" cx="12" cy="12" r="8"></circle>
    </defs>
    <g id="Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="icon-dot">
            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
            <g id="Mask" fill-rule="nonzero"></g>
            <g id="Blue/" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#0A4ACE">
                <rect id="Rectangle" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"></rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

To anyone stumbling across this in the future:

The issue was not technically with `mat-icon` as I suspected. The error in rendering `svg`'s was due to Sketch's non-unique mask and path `id`'s.

So to resolve this I used ShadowDom encapsulation which makes each `svg` unique within its own DOM, and wrote my own injection.

#### myComponent.component.ts

```js
...
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
...

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    this.iconRegistry.getNamedSvgIcon(this.name).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      svg => {
        this.setSvgElement(svg)
      },
        (err: Error) => console.warn(`Error retrieving icon: ${err.message}`)
    )
  }

  private setSvgElement(svg: SVGElement){
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.shadowRoot.appendChild(svg)
  }
```

Comment: OMG, you saved my day! My issue comes from Sketch's class. The export used the same path class, which made confusion for matIcon. They should differentiate classes by files, but it seems they don't.